# Работа с интерфейсами

Tags: golang

У меня есть несколько структур, в каждой из них есть общее свойство Id. Мне необходимо передать эти структуры в функцию и выполнить операции над ними.

```
func (diff *difference) searchDiff(arr1, arr2 []interface{}) {
    for i := range arr1 {
        for j := range arr2 {
            if arr1[i].Id == arr2[j].Id { // Как мне проверить их свойства?
               ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблемы в том, что я не могу в качестве типа параметров указать какую-то конкретную структуру, ибо они разные. Но есть у них у каждой Id int.
Первое, что пришло в голову - в качестве типа использовать интерфейс. Но получить свойства у меня не получится. Также подумал про reflect (проверять типы каждый раз), но это как-то некошерно. Ибо, если будет структур 10 похожих, будет просто дублироваться код. Может, есть какой нибудь более просто способ?

Передаю структуры типа этой:

```
type Object struct {
   Id int `xml:"id,attr"`
   Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
   Address string `xml:"address,attr"`
   Code string `xml:"code,attr"`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В GO нет свойств. В GO есть поля и функции. Интерфейс может содержать только функции.

Если вы хотите, чтобы структура реализовывала какай-либо интерфейс, то вы должны реализовать для структуры все функции интерфейса. Причём, для структуры надо только создать функции с такой же сигнатурой, что и в интерфейсе (деклалировать что реализован такой-то интерфейс не нужно).

Пример:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Identifier interface {
    GetValue() int32
}

type Struct1 struct {
    id int32
}

// Эта функция реализует функцию интерфейса Identifier
func (s Struct1) GetValue() int32 {
    return s.id
}

type Struct2 struct {
    id int32
}

// Эта функция реализует функцию интерфейса Identifier
func (s Struct2) GetValue() int32 {
    return s.id
}

func main() {
    var ids = []Identifier{Struct1{id: 1}, Struct2{id: 2}}

    for _, id := range ids {
        value := id.GetValue()
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: а как мне быть, если мне нужно передать массив структур в функцию? т.е к примеру searchDiff([]Struct1{Struct1{1, "lol"},Struct1{1, "lol"}}) вот так? у меня данные в таком виде

Comment: @Алексей это хороший вопрос, который можно оформить отдельно.  Откройте новый вопрос и вам его распишут.

Answer (score 1):

Простого способа, увы, нет.

Связанно это с тем что []interface{} (slice of interfaces) != []Object (slice of Objects) != []IDer (slice of interface IDer). Эти структуры по разному отображаются в памяти - поэтому компилятор отказывается делать эти неявные преобразования автоматически.

Можно, конечно, каждый раз явно заставлять это делать

```
arr := make([]IDer, len(arr1))
for i := range arr1 {
    arr[i] = IDer(arr1[i])
}
```

но некрасиво и кушает память.

Читая твой вопрос я задумался над тем что же ты хочешь делать внутри searchDiff.
Уже из самого вопроса напрашивается вывод, что 
ты хочешь определить *поведение*, но не поведение элементов, а именно поведение *слайса* элементов. А идиоматически поведение задается через интерфейсы.

**Вариант 1**

Определяем типы:

```
type IDer interface {
    ID() int
}

// Object implements IDer
func (obj *Object) ID() int {
    return obj.Id
}
```

И слайс интерфесов IDer

```
type IDerSlice []IDer
```

После чего твоя функция searchDiff определяется как

```
func (diff *difference) searchDiff(arr1, arr2 IDerSlice) {
    for i := range arr1 {
        for j := range arr2 {
            if arr1[i].ID() < arr2[j].ID() {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Все, можно работать.
https://play.golang.org/p/gnTnf23973

```
package main

import ()

type difference struct{}

type Object struct {
    Id      int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name    string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Address string `xml:"address,attr"`
    Code    string `xml:"code,attr"`
}

type IDer interface {
    ID() int
}

// Object implements IDer
func (obj *Object) ID() int {
    return obj.Id
}

type IDerSlice []IDer

func (diff *difference) searchDiff(arr1, arr2 IDerSlice) {
    for i := range arr1 {
        for j := range arr2 {
            if arr1[i].ID() < arr2[j].ID() {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // Обратить внимание что создаем мы именно IDerSlice
    arr1 := IDerSlice{
        &Object{
            Id:      1,
            Name:    "object1",
            Address: "earth",
            Code:    "er",
        },
        &Object{
            Id:      2,
            Name:    "object2",
            Address: "moon",
            Code:    "mn",
        },

    }
    arr2 := IDerSlice{
        &Object{
            Id:      10,
            Name:    "object10",
            Address: "mars",
            Code:    "mr",
        },
        &Object{
            Id:      11,
            Name:    "object11",
            Address: "phobos",
            Code:    "ph",
        },
        &Object{
            Id:      12,
            Name:    "object12",
            Address: "deimos",
            Code:    "de",
        },

    }

    diff := &difference{}

    diff.searchDiff(arr1, arr2)
}
```

Обрати внимание что мы создаем слайсы объектов именно как IDerSlice, те как коллекцию элементов с которыми мы хотим работать единообразно посредством интерфейса. Поэтому *все* данные из нижележащих структур придется проксировать геттерами и сеттерами в этот интерфейс, что неудобно, но это именно то что ты и хотел - единообразная работа с разными структурами данных через поведение.

**Вариант 2**

Если же у тебя будут только слайсы объектов нужного тебе типа, то придется делать так как сделано в пакете sort.
https://play.golang.org/p/e5Dt7-Ocnx

```
package main

import (
    //"fmt"
)

type difference struct{}

type Object struct {
    Id      int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name    string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Address string `xml:"address,attr"`
    Code    string `xml:"code,attr"`
}

type Object2 struct {
    Id       int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name2    string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Address2 string `xml:"address,attr"`
    Code2    string `xml:"code,attr"`
}

type searchDiffInterface interface {
    Len() int
    GetID(i int) int
}

type ObjectSlice []*Object

type Object2Slice []*Object2

func (obj ObjectSlice) GetID(i int) int {
    return obj[i].Id
}
func (obj ObjectSlice) Len() int {
    return len(obj)
}

func (obj Object2Slice) GetID(i int) int {
    return obj[i].Id
}
func (obj Object2Slice) Len() int {
    return len(obj)
}

func (diff *difference) searchDiff(arr1, arr2 searchDiffInterface) {
    for i := 0; i < arr1.Len(); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < arr2.Len(); j++ {
            if arr1.GetID(i) == arr2.GetID(j) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    arr1 := []*Object{
        &Object{
            Id:      1,
            Name:    "object1",
            Address: "earth",
            Code:    "er",
        },
        &Object{
            Id:      2,
            Name:    "object2",
            Address: "moon",
            Code:    "mn",
        },

    }
    arr2 := []*Object2{
        &Object2{
            Id:      10,
            Name2:    "object10",
            Address2: "mars",
            Code2:    "mr",
        },
        &Object2{
            Id:      11,
            Name2:    "object11",
            Address2: "phobos",
            Code2:    "ph",
        },
        &Object2{
            Id:      12,
            Name2:    "object12",
            Address2: "deimos",
            Code2:    "de",
        },

    }

    diff := &difference{}

    // Обрати внимание явное приведение типов теперь тут
    diff.searchDiff(ObjectSlice(arr1), Object2Slice(arr2))
}
```

Какой бы из подходов ты не выбрал, тебе придется где-то явно приводить тип.
Доопредели searchDiffInterface всеми методами которые тебе нужны в searchDiff.

Если они у тебя все одинаковы, или очень похожи, то можно воспользоваться кодогенерацией с помощью go generate или трюком, похожим на sort.Reverse.

И в конце концов вариант через reflect (с автоматическим приведением типов), но он **ужасно** медленный.

```
func (diff *difference) searchDiff(arr1, arr2 interface{}) {
    arr1slice := reflect.ValueOf(arr1)
    arr2slice := reflect.ValueOf(arr2)

    for i := 0; i < arr1slice.Len(); i++  {
        for j := 0; j < arr2slice.Len(); j++ {
            val_arr1i := arr1slice.Index(i)
            val_arr2j := arr2slice.Index(j)
            arr1id := val_arr1i.Elem().FieldByName("Id")
            arr2id := val_arr2j.Elem().FieldByName("Id")

            fmt.Println(val_arr1i.Elem(), val_arr2j.Elem())
            if arr1id == arr2id {
                //...
            }

        }
    }   
}
```