# Передача аргумента в функцию с динамическим типом структуры

Tags: golang, структуры-данных

Как правильно передать в функцию и работать в ней с массивом структур, но при этом тип структур заранее неизвестен. 
К примеру есть функция searchDiff, которая принимает массив, в котором лежат структуры. 
К примеру так:

```
searchDiff([]Struct1{Struct1{2, "azaza"}, Struct1{1, "lol"}})
searchDiff([]Struct2{Struct2{1, "azaza", "param1"}, Struct2{2, "lol", "param2"}})
```

У каждой структуры есть общие свойства, к примеру - Id
А функция будет определяться как-то так:

```
func searchDiff(arr []myInterface)
```

Да, можно создать интерфейс, и в каждой структуре описать методы. Но, насколько я понял, что переменная с типом []interface{} не является интерфейсом.

Как передавать в функцию массив, в котором будут лежать структуры с динамическим типом данных?

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю в контексте [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488304)

Тут надо обратить внимание на то, как объявляются поля у структуры и как их потом можно применять.

```
package pkg01

type Struct1 struct {
    id    int32
    value string
}
```

Так поля объявленные с маленькой буквы будут видны только в рамках пакета `pkg01`. Для остальных пакетов они не видны.

```
package main

import "pkg01"

func main() {
    var s1 pkg01.Struct1
    s1.id = 1 // ошибка: s1.id undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method id)
}
```

Что бы дать стороннему пакету оперировать полем id вам надо либо сделать его публичным, либо написать для него функции get/set.

В GO публичные поля - это поля объявленные с большой буквы:

```
package pkg01

type Struct1 struct {
    Id    int32
    Value string
}
```

Используем:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "pkg01"

func main() {
    var s1 pkg01.Struct1
    s1.Id = 1
    s1.Value = "one"
    fmt.Println(s1)
}
```

Но можно не раскрывать поля структуры, а создать функции get/set и функцию `New` для инициализации полей. По принятому соглашению для GO get функция называется также, как и поле (но с первой большой буквы), для set функции добавляют префикс `Set`:

```
package pkg01

type Struct1 struct {
    id    int32
    value string
}

func NewStruct1(id int32, value string) Struct1 {
    return Struct1{id: id, value: value}
}

func (s *Struct1) Id() int32 {
    return s.id
}

func (s *Struct1) Value() string {
    return s.value
}

func (s *Struct1) SetValue(value string) {
    s.value = value
}
```

Используем:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "my-labs/lab002/pkg01"

func main() {
    var s1 pkg01.Struct1 = pkg01.NewStruct1(1, "one")
    fmt.Printf("id = %v, value = '%v'\n", s1.Id(), s1.Value())
}
```

А теперь стоит обратить внимание на, то как в GO реализуется интерфейс. Чтобы структура реализовала интерфейс достаточно того, чтобы в ней присутствовали функции, объявленные в интерфейсе:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "pkg01"

type Interface1 interface {
    Id() int32
    Value() string
    SetValue(value string)
}

func main() {
    var s1 pkg01.Struct1 = pkg01.NewStruct1(1, "one")
    var a Interface1 = &s1

    fmt.Printf("id = %v, value = '%v'\n", a.Id(), a.Value())
}
```

Так, чтобы вторая структура могла обрабатываться согласно интерфейсу `Interface1`, в ней надо только прописать те же функции, что и в интерфейсе:

```
package pkg02

type Struct2 struct {
    id    int32
    value string
}

func NewStruct2(id int32, value string) Struct2 {
    return Struct2{id: id, value: value}
}

func (s *Struct2) Id() int32 {
    return s.id
}

func (s *Struct2) Value() string {
    return s.value
}

func (s *Struct2) SetValue(value string) {
    s.value = value
}
```

Таким образом, разные структуры можно обрабатывать в одном массиве под заданным интерфейсом `Interface1`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "pkg01"
import "pkg02"

type Interface1 interface {
    Id() int32
    Value() string
    SetValue(value string)
}

func main() {
    var s1 pkg01.Struct1 = pkg01.NewStruct1(1, "one")

    var s2 pkg02.Struct2 = pkg02.NewStruct2(2, "two")

    var array = []Interface1{&s1, &s2}

    for _, s := range array {
        s.SetValue(s.Value() + "!!!")

        fmt.Printf("id = %v, value = '%v'\n", s.Id(), s.Value())
    }
}
```

Comment: опять-таки мы получаем "массив интерфейсов".  И передавать мы будем его, а не массив структур.

Comment: Ну вот собственно в доках типа решение https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: @Алексей Т.е. вы не хотите создавать еще один массив? Тогда создайте объект итератор, инициализируйте его текущим массивом и передавайте в функцию.